# Trouble deploying a Zend Framework site with Capistrano: SSH Authentication error

Tags: git, authentication, capistrano, ssh-keys

I've been following [this tutorial](http://www.wjgilmore.com/blog/entry/deploying_php_websites_with_capistrano) trying to deploy my Zend Framework site via Capistrano. I've gotten almost everything to work: My server recognizes the signature from my private key when I SSH in, so I no longer need to enter a password.

Unfortunately, when I run the command cap deploy:setup, I get the following error output:

```
    servers: ["server@domain"]
connection failed for: server@domain (Net::SSH::Authentication::AgentError: unknown response from agent: 1, "\x00\x00\x00,\x01\x00\x00\x00'SSH-2.0-Ruby/Net::SSH_2.6.7 x64-mingw32")
```

I'm completely unfamiliar with Ruby as well as the points behind SSH and public key authentication, so I really have no idea what's going on.

If it helps, I had to generate my public/private key pair using the GIT Bash tool, and I'm also using the Ruby command prompt in a different window. My gut is telling me that Ruby does not have access to the private key and/or does not have the key's password cached.

Comment: What's the user variable set to in the capistrano config?  Does `ssh <capistrano-user>@server` work?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/LuGkkCKz has the deploy.rb file I'm using. Well, sort of. There are placeholders in there where they should be.

I may also have my system set up wrong, because I can only run ssh from the command line in Git Bash--not from a normal command prompt, nor from the one that runs Ruby. At any rate, when I do run ssh <capistrano-user>@server, it works fine--doesn't even ask for the private key password. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding `default_run_options[:pty] = true` and changing `set :deploy_via, :copy` to `set :deploy_via, :remote_cache`

Comment: Tried that. It didn't work.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Just to see if it would work, I also tried using `set :scm_passphrase, "laServerPassword"`, but even that got the same response. So I'm starting to think that there may be a problem on the server side...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/WCFg3MNL - there's a working unicorn config that I use (modified of course).  Maybe give it a try?

Comment: OK, it seems like having Pageant running was interfering with Capistrano in some way--once I turned it off the error went away. Unfortunately, now I have another error that I'm trying to work around. I've started a new question here: http://bit.ly/139yvoX

Comment: Looks like that question was removed.  Did you figure it out?

Comment: I thought I had, but then another problem popped up. Here's the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870967/trouble-using-capistrano-with-a-local-git-repository/16871004?iemail=1&noredirect=1#16871004) to the new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bug appears to be an underlying net-ssh gem problem, as reported here:

https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/issues/92

The issue appears to be with 64-bit windows (applications)

Since it isn't resolved, your options are to downgrade to 32 bit versions of ruby/ssh agent/ etc.

Comment: I actually wound up just using the Git GUI in Windows, which works beautifully. Nevertheless, I appreciate your help. Thanks!