# Trouble using Capistrano with a local git repository

Tags: windows, git, capistrano

I'm trying to use Capistrano to deploy my Zend Framework application using a git repository. I'm deploying from a Windows 7 machine to an Ubuntu server. I've created the repository, and whenever I try running cap:deploy, I get the following errors:

```
** [hostname.domain :: out] fatal: '/home/<username>/web_docs/<appname>' does not appear 
   to be a git repository
** [hostname.domain :: out] fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I have sanitized copy of my deploy.rb file here. I've got a perfectly good git repository on my local machine, but Capistrano appears to be looking for a copy of the repository on the server before it's even deployed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy from a local repository, you'll have to use a strategy like `:copy` or `:rsync`. Capistrano tries to clone from the repository from the server side, expecting it to be a remote repository.

Comment: When I try using `set :deploy_via, :copy`, I get an error that says "Fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository.

You say that Capistrano tries to clone from the repository from the server side. If I wanted to do that, how can I keep the remote repository in sync with the local one?

Comment: Please forgive the questions: I'm completely new to using Git and Capistrano.

Comment: without the deploy file I can't say much.

Comment: Oh sorry, though I'd posted the pastebin link. [Here it is](http://pastebin.com/BkVjcFcA)

Comment: Incidentally, I originally got the file by following W.J. Gillmore's tutorial in his book Easy PHP Websites with the Zend Framework. There's a snippet of the  tutorial on [his blog](http://www.wjgilmore.com/blog/entry/deploying_php_websites_with_capistrano).

Comment: You should still be able to do `set :deploy_via, :remote_cache` so long as the machine can connect via SSH to the git repo - even if the git repo is local (I do this on my Linode).  Have you tried fiddling with `cap shell` and seeing if you can get more details through that?

Comment: Well, there's one more point I should mention. The tutorial also says to use ssh-agent to cache the passphrase for my SSH key. I did that, but for some reason every time I run cap:deploy, it still asks me for my passphrase. Also, I have to run ssh-agend from git bash. Could this somehow be related?

Comment: @CDub: That sounds like a good idea, but unfortunately I don't know where to begin with cap shell. Any suggestions?

Comment: Running `cap:deploy` and having it ask for your passphrase after running `ssh-agent` leads me to believe that the user in the SSH key is different than the deploy user, even if the passwords are the same.  `cap shell` behaves just like bash.  I'd start with `whoami` and `pwd` to see who it's logging in as and what the current directory is.

Comment: OK, this is starting to make sense now. I think that ssh-kegen was making the key for the user@hostname that I have set for my (Windows) production machine, which is obviously different from my host. I'll do some Googling for a way to set the username/hostname for a key generated under Windows--if that doesn't work, I'll ask again. Thanks!

Comment: I'm actually away from my development machine right now, so I can't really try this out, so I'll just ask: would `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C serverUsername@domain.ext` create a proper key for me, or do I have to do something else?

Comment: OK, I'm starting to think there's something else going on here. I have to run ssh-agent from Git Bash. When I do, I can then ssh to my server without entering the key's passphrase. But anywhere else, and key asks me for it. What's more, I can only run ruby--and thus Capistrano--from the RUBY command prompt. And it's as if the two are not sharing anything, because any time I run cap deploy, I get permission denied errors from the server.

Comment: I'm starting to think it might just be better for me to deploy straight from git. Now to actually figure out how to do that...

Comment: It sounds like you need to copy the SSH key from your Windows box over to the server, under the user who is the deploy user, in the `authorized_keys` file.  (Sorry for the nasty fragmented sentence. Hopefully it makes sense)

Comment: only the public key though.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "under the user who is the deploy user". I do have an `authorized_keys` file in my .ssh directory on my server (`/home/username/.ssh`, like the book said). My username on my Windows box is different from my Ubuntu username, but that shouldn't make any difference, should it?

Comment: no, it doesn't. If you deploy to user `username`, your public key needs to be present in `/home/username/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: I eventually wound up just using git by itself. Capistrano proved to be just too much trouble to implement, and with the good gui that Git for Windows has, it works just fine. But thanks any way for all your help--I really appreciate it.